# Quelle est la signification du mot québécois « vingnenne » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, adjectifs, québec, noms, paroles-de-chanson

Il y a une chanson de Plume Latraverse (chanteur, auteur, compositeur, etc.) dont un mot des paroles est « vingnenne ». Le titre de la chanson c'est *La p'tite vingnenne pis l'gros torrieu*. Le contexte de la chanson est que la p'tite vingnenne est une prostituée et le gros torrieu dont on parle est son proxénète. Je pense que la signification de « vingnienne » n'est pas « prostituée », parce la signification de « torrieu » n'est pas « proxénète ». Quelle est la vraie signification de « vingnenne » ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Vingnenne* serait un juron : il apparaît dans la section [*autres jurons québécois*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Annexe:Sacres_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois#Autres_jurons_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois) de l'article du Wiktionnaire sur les *sacres québécois*<sup>1</sup> sous deux graphies : *vindienne, vingnenne* ; l'article [*vindienne*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/vindienne) parle d'un juron populaire et donne comme exemple :

> Quant aux jurons, je reconnais qu’ils représentent pour la traduction
>   un pari presque impossible : pas évident d’exporter notre vaisselle
>   d’église dans des w.c. anglo-saxons ou un bordel français, et
>   vice-versa. Mais bon yeux de vindienne de taboire, est-ce une raison
>   pour ne pas essayer ?
>
> [ Louis Hamelin ds. [*Le Devoir*](https://www.ledevoir.com/opinion/chroniques/418875/traductions-infideles-2-de-5-de-truchement-a-trucmuche-et-de-l-importance-du-nombre) en 2014, ds. Wiktionnaire à *vindienne* ]

Le [GPFC](http://bibnum2.banq.qc.ca/bna/numtxt/179630.pdf) contient *vinguienne*, l'interjection pour une « sorte de juron » ou en tournure *vinguienne de* [nom] dont on indique l'équivalence avec une... « sorte de juron » ; peu utile mais ça semble être une variante graphique pour un *juron* encore une fois (je pense que c'est le même que dans la question). L'article Wikipédia sur les [*sacres québécois*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacre_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois) indique qu'il y a polymorphisme et qu'ils peuvent aussi être utilisés comme noms mais on n'explique pas exactement ce qu'ils pourraient signifier dans ce genre d'emploi ; on peut essayer de déduire à l'aide d'exemples :

> « P'tit câlice! » (Petit garnement !)
>  « Toé, mon p'tit crisse! »
>   (Toi, mon petit garnement !)
>  « Viens donc me dire ça dans' face
>   mon gros crisse! » (Viens donc près de moi pour me répéter ce que tu
>   viens de dire !)
>  « Toé, mon p'tit maudit! » (Toi, mon petit
>   garnement !)
>  « Mon p'tit mausus, arviens icitte tu'suite! » (Mon
>   petit garnement, reviens ici tout de suite !)
>  « T'es ben mieux de
>   m'écouter, mon ostie! » (Tu devrais m'écouter attentivement !)
>  «
>   Viens icitte, mon tabarnak! » (Viens me voir, petit con !)
>  « Bin
>   mon tabarnak! » (Ah bien toi là !)
>  « Hé, mon torrieux! »
>   (Emmerdeur !)
>   ?
>   [ Exemples tirés de l'article Wiktionnaire « Sacres québécois ». ]

Plus généralement, les adjectifs [*petit*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/petit) et [*gros*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/gros) sont fréquemment employés pour ajuster l'aspect minoratif ou mélioratif, voire hypocoristique, du nom qui les accompagne ainsi que pour une panoplie d'autres nuances. Autrement le choix exact du juron peut relever d'une question autre que sémantique (la rime par exemple, surtout avec *torrieux* dans la chanson mais aussi *vingnenne* avec *cenne*...).

---

D'après moi, le juron substantivé (*vingnenne, torrieu*) désigne de manière générique une *personne* avec une connotation surtout *péjorative* (comme un [*vaurien*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/crisse) par exemple ou la personne se méritant notre [colère/indignation](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tabarnac#Nom_commun) pour une raison etc.). La *p'tite vingnenne* serait à mon avis l'hypocoristique appliqué au péjoratif et *l'gros torrieu* serait un plus haut degré du même péjoratif ; c'est peut-être aussi littéralement leur caractéristique physique que d'être petite et gros ? Si *vingnenne* est un juron je ne vois pas pourquoi alors on aurait un sens différent de si on avait eu recours aux principaux jurons comme *(p'tite) crisse* ou *(gros) tabarnac* dans la chanson, hormis le [degré](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacre_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois#Degr%C3%A9_des_sacres).

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> C'est le seul juron de l'article que je ne connais pas et il ne représente pas une [atténuation](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Annexe:Sacres_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois#D%C3%A9riv%C3%A9s_par_att%C3%A9nuation) par déformation d'un quelconque autre mot que je puisse identifier (par ailleurs il me fait penser à *bonyenne* vu la finale) mais une chose est sûre, c'est que [Plume Latraverse](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plume_Latraverse) connaît son juron...</sub>

Answer (score 3):

d'après [ce site](https://www.dufrancaisaufrancais.com/mots-mysteres/), vingnenne signifie "rusé ou malin". Ici au féminin pour la petite rusée, maligne. T**ieu est un sacre qui vient de "tort à Dieu"